# How to find login url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I used a plugin to change my login page URL in WordPress and now I forgot it as I have not used it for long time. I have username and pass but not the login URL. How do I find it out either from database or website files.

Comment: what's the plugins name? check in the database as the new url ir probably kept there

Comment: iThemes i guess

Answer (score 1):

Using FTP, look in `/wp-content/plugins/` and rename any security or login URL plugins, like `iThemes`; that will force deactivate them.

That should return your standard login to `http://example.com/wp-admin/`.

Then, you can try your current login/password or use the 'Forget Password" link.

Answer (score -1):

Try the standard url "/wp-admin". 
I think he will redirect to url you have set in the plugin.

Comment: It redirects to page not found page.

Comment: some plugin add a security feature to change the /wp-login default address so people do not try to brute force the login form, but the key is to save the new url you set

Comment: It was option. I didn't say it works. Which plugin do u use?

Comment: Look into the database or know for sure which plugin you have used for it.